# Titanium, Js function to display XML text field text

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, var

-XML

```
<TextField class="username" 
           hintText="Enter Nickname" 
           height="40" 
           width="Ti.UI.CENTER" />
```

-JS

```
function signup(e){
    alert(is this ur name + "var");
}
```

i am trying to get a user to enter a username and then put that in a variable to use or display elsewhere. the JS code is an example function of what i want to do. keeping in mind that the xml and js code are not in the same file.

Comment: How do you want the user to enter his name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an "id" attribute to the TextField, so that you can access it in the controller, for example, modifying your code, lets assume the [Alloy controller](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers) is named "GetUsername":

```
/* GetUsername.xml */
<Alloy>
    <TextField id="usernameInput" class="username" 
           hintText="Enter Nickname" 
           height="40" 
           width="Ti.UI.CENTER" />
</Alloy>
```

This is the controller JS file that backs up the view:

```
/* GetUsername.js */
function signup(e){
    alert("is this ur name " + $.usernameInput.value);
}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. I don't know what i was doing wrong I tred this before but it didn't work, now it does :-)